# DataGridView bound to list(of T) change column type

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a `datagridview` the is bound to a `List(of T)`.

```
Private BodyComponents As New List(Of BodyComponent)
Private BodyBinding As BindingSource


Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()


    ' Set the bindingsource
    BodyBinding = New BindingSource(BodyComponents, Nothing)

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    dgvBodyOverview.DataSource = BodyBinding

    ....
```

All the items in the list represent a object with multiple properties, one of these is material `As String`. I have a large list of available materials where the user should be able to choose from. How can I make this available in the `datagridview` as drop-down box?

Info: The materials are read at run-time when the dialog is opened and not hardcoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the column types, so after the columns are created replace the `Material` one with a new `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` you created:

```
dgv1.DataSource = ...

Dim cbo = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
Dim oldCol = dgv1.Columns("Material")
' copy or set prop values
cbo.HeaderText = oldCol.HeaderText
cbo.Name = oldCol.Name
cbo.DataSource = MaterialsList
cbo.DataPropertyName = "Material"

' replace the column
dgv1.Columns.Remove(oldCol)
dgv1.Columns.Add(cbo)
' cant set the Display Index until it is in the DGV
cbo.DisplayIndex = oldCol.DisplayIndex
```

---

In cases where you need the column to display one thing but save something like an Id to the DGV's `DataSource`, you'd do that thru the combo column's `DataSource`.

Use either a `DataTable` query result which contains the `Id` and text you want to show, or a simple `List` those Name-Value pairs:

```
cbo.DataSource = Materials              ' == a DT or List of Name-Id
cbo.DisplayName = "MaterialName"        ' col or prop name to show
cbo.ValueMember = "Id"                  ' value to save
```

The datatype of the `ValueMember` needs to match that of the column it maps to in the data source (`cbo.DataPropertyName`)

Comment: What is best to use when there is no alternate `Id` required? Just the string needs to be shown and saved.

Comment: Thats what the top part - above the HR  does - sets MaterialsList as the DataSource - assuming it is a plain `List(of String)` - you didnt say much about what it was